# Sending a file from front end to back end taking too long

Tags: javascript, c#

I am currently building a web application that takes an excel file uploaded by the user (using Javascript), sends it to the back-end (which uses C#) and searches for a specific field before returning the answer. My code so far seems to work fine for small files, however the files the users will provide are around 4MB each. When i upload a file of that size and follow the code using breakpoints i realize that it does not even reach the C# code, the connection seems to fail and i believe this is because it takes too long to pass the file over.

The following is part of my javascript code:

```js
document.getElementById('selectedFile').addEventListener('change', function (event) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function () {
            filename = event.target.files[0].name;
            fileContent = btoa(new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode( new Uint8Array(this.result)));
            console.log(fileContent);
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.files[0]);
    }, 

    $("#btnRunReport").on("click",
        function () {
            if (!validateFilename()) {
                showErrorMsg("Please upload an EXCEL file with the extension .xlsx");
                return;
            }
            var request = runReportRequest;
            authorizeAndExecuteAjaxRequest(request);
        }
);
```

```js
function runReportRequest() {
    toggleRunButton();
    $("#textAreaRow").show();
    var token = getUserToken();
    RunMT4ConfigHub.invoke("RunReport", token, filename, fileContent);
}
```

All of this code works perfectly until a larger file is sent. Is there a way i can get the connection to last longer or maybe send my file over in parts, to avoid having the connection fail?

Comment: May i suggest you to send the payload using the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FormData)API instead of converting to base64? it seems as a blocking operation on the front-end and base64 files also increases the transfer size. This would improve some performance for sure. I hope your environment supports that.

Comment: The company i work for prefer to not use APIs, they want it to all be locally built however if there is no other solution then i will give it a go

Comment: FormData API i'ts a client web API present in all major browsers.  you can check [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=formdata) the reach of this **native** API

Answer (score 1):

Add in your web.config the following:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxx" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I think file size is limited to 4mb by default. (where xxx is kb)

Comment: I double checked the files and it turns out base64 turns the file into around 11 MB. I tried placing the maxRequestLength to 11MB (11264kb) but i got the same problem.